# How to import data from different files into arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, import

I have a list of files, and want to import data into an array. I keep trying different ways and none of them seem to work, and throw up different errors

```
M = 5
files = ('t1.txt', 't2.txt', 't3.txt', 't4.txt', 't5.txt')

data = numpy.empty([M])
for x in files: 
    data[files.index(x)] = np.loadtxt(x)
```

This gives the error `"ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence."`, which I assume is because files.index is not giving me an integer? but I tried manually setting an integer there and counting upwards, which didn't work either?

Comment: What did you *expect*?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting an error is because np.loadtxt(x) returns an array, and you are trying to set a particular index of data with that array, but you can only set array elements with scalars, as far as I know.  I'm not sure what exactly you need, but maybe a list would work better:

```py
files = ('t1.txt', 't2.txt', 't3.txt', 't4.txt', 't5.txt')

data = [None] * M
for x in files: 
    data[files.index(x)] = np.loadtxt(x)
```